# HIGH CPU UTILISATION OF VM

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, sap

we are facing a peculiar behavior in our production environment. We are using vmware vsphere 5.1 as our visualization solution and have many production machines running on it. It is a cluster of 3 hp BL680C Gen7 servers. On July 1st 2015, we observed that many of the vm's are running slow and the guest cpu utilization was showing a steady 100%. analyzing the host machines revealed that the cpu utilization of all the three hosts were touching 100% starting suddenly from around 5.30AM in the morning, the same day.

Observations.

1)when application(primarily sap(java)) was stopped in the guest machine, cpu of guest dropped to less than 10%. Starting the apps again got the cpu utilization to 100%.

2)SAP jstart process was using most of the cpu.

3)Analysis of the java core of jstart process revealed that they are not using 25%of cpu, but top showing 100% utilization.(more than 100 in case of multiple cores).

3)we also have ibm web-sphere running. We observed similar behavior on those too.

4)Guest OS restart resolved the issue.

Any one faced similar issue..? Any light on what might be happening. 
Suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue started on 1st July, it may have been due to the leap second added at the end of 30th June. If this is the cause, then running "date -s now" may have fixed it; rebooting likewise.

Google leap second java linux (or similar) for more information.